# Devise not redirecting to signin page on invalid attempt with custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

Using Devise and custom routes, whenever the user has a invalid signin attempt (wrong pass), then Rails isn't redirecting back to the sign-in page. If I don't use custom routes, then it works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Goal: I want to use /signin instead of /users/sign_in

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "user_sessions" },:skip => [:sessions] do
   get 'signin' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
   post 'signin' => 'user_sessions#create', :as => :user_session
   delete 'signout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
   get 'signout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

inside UserSessionsController/create:

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
```

Server output when using custom route /signin:

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
```

Server output when using default route /user/sign_in:

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
Processing by UserSessionsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2gqKTGWPv69HpVp7oSEg2tRDj5FU453my7LhKm0xu7E=", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"SIGN IN"}
Rendered user_sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/user_sessions (56.6ms)
```

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => admin_session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

with:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => admin_session_path) do |f| %>
```

in the sessions/new.html.erb file worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been posted a couple months ago but I hot the same issue, and after fighting it for a few hours, overwriting Devise SessionController, Devise Custom Failure, debugging through, etc.., I finally found out what was going on and I decided to share the solution so you guys won't have to go through that.
The error 'Completed 401 Unauthorized in XXms' happens within the create method of SessionController at the lign: resource =  build_resource(...). And the resource cannot be built since the resource is not passed to the server. Now the problem resides in WHY the resource isn't passed to the server? I'm using JQUERY mobile which post the sign_in as an AJAX call, which JQUERY cannot upload data like that through AJAX.
Yuu need to add to your signin form the data-ajax=false:
in Devise/sessions/new.html.erb modify the form to look like this:

```
form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_url, html: {data: {ajax: false}}) do |f|
```

Hope that helps someone down the road.